# Указать путь к директории через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, wordpress

Есть такой код JS

```
style.href = "other/pagepiling/jquery.pagepiling.min.css";
```

Но мне нужно что то вроде такого

style.href = "http://acquirev01.myjino.ru/wp-content/themes/acquirev/other/pagepiling/jquery.pagepiling.min.css";

Как такое сделать так, чтобы при смене домена путь к файлу оставался всегда верным?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
<script>style.href = '<?php echo get_style_href(); ?>';</script>
```

Функция `get_style_href()` должна возвращать нужный URL.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `wp_localize_script` в который передавайте любые переменный из php к js:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'some-name',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/assets/js/main.js',
        [],
        '1.0.0',
        true
    );
    wp_localize_script(
        'some-name',
        [
            'url'   => get_template_directory_uri()
        ]
    );
}
```

js-file:

```
style.href = some.url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Уберите имя домена с адреса:

```
style.href = "/wp-content/themes/acquirev/other/pagepiling/jquery.pagepiling.min.css";
```